# Msi gtx 760 sli

Tags: nvidia-geforce, sli

I want to buy another MSI GTX 760 4GB OC to have two in an SLI configuration. My current setup is this:

```
Cpu: Intel i7 6700K 
Mobo: MSI Z170 M9 ACK
Ssd: 2x Samsung 850evo 500GB
Psu: Corsair RM 650
RAM: Kingston Hyperx DDR4 2666MHZ 15cl
Gpu: MSI GTX 760 4GB OC
Case: Corsair 780T Black
```

Will my current system support a second graphics card? Will I have to upgrade anything before it will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motherboard [supports SLI](http://us.msi.com/product/mb/Z170A-GAMING-M9-ACK.html#hero-specification), so no problem there.

While the RM-650 isn't ideal for SLI in general, it's a [fairly decent unit](http://www.jonnyguru.com/modules.php?name=NDReviews&file=print&reid=363) and has the required connectors (4x 6+2-pin PCIe). It should be able to provide the power for this specific situation. The MSI GTX970 will requires about 150-200W under load (tests at [bit-tech](http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/2013/07/04/msi-geforce-gtx-760-twin-frozr-oc-2gb-revie/8) and [Guru3D](http://www.guru3d.com/articles_pages/geforce_gtx_760_msi_gaming_review,5.html)), so should be okay.

Only potential problem is if you overclock everything and burn both the CPU and GPUs at the same time -- that's the only way I'd see it getting close to the limits of the RM-650.

<s>Other possible issue is whether the case has enough room/cooling capacity for the two cards, but case isn't mentioned so can't really tell.</s> *Edit*: Case is large and roomy, should be no problem there either. Just check the GPU temps are okay under load to make sure they're getting enough airflow as there's no possibility of a side-of-case fan.

Comment: I edited my setup with the case

Comment: While your answer is correct and valuable to the questioner, this kind of reccomendations are off-topic on this site.

Comment: No worries @KarmaEDV, thanks for the downvote for my valuable answer. That'll learn me for trying to help.

Comment: @Ash I know right? I had to learn it myself. It pissed me off at first, but then I got assimilated by the self-policing spirit of this community.

Comment: @KarmaEDV tell me where I needed to post it then.

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren Don't know, maybe TomsHardware Forums?

Comment: @Ash With enough room/ cooling do you mean watercooling? Because that is my plan for the future (custom, EK)

Comment: @KarmaEDV isn't thare a hardware forum on stack exchange

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren Got you: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oke I didn't know that I'm sorry

Comment: @KarmaEDV: I'm not sure I see the problem -- http://superuser.com/help/on-topic: `Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
    computer hardware,`
It is not a recommendation, it is an answerable question, it may be useful to other people with similar setups. But the mods will do their thing I guess if they see fit..._edit_: it's also not a recommendation request, so is potentially OT for hardwarerecs anyway, which only has a stubbed "on topic" section at this point in time.

Comment: @Ash Sure, and I don't want to seem petty by answering your last comment. But I interpret the same page you posted differenetly: "and it is not about … asking for a product [...] recommendation"

Comment: @KarmaEDV This question is off-topic on Hardware Recs, but on-topic here. OP isn't asking _what_ graphics card to buy, he is asking _if_ it would work in his current setup. I do agree that it does need work however.

Comment: @Cfinley: I just find it amusing that some users are using downvotes to punish answers they <i>say themselves are valuable</i> because they believe the question is off-topic, rather than just voting to close the question...

Comment: @Ash I agree. Don't let the downvote get to you. People will find any reason to downvote you.

Comment: Alright, my bad. Retracted the downvote. Mea Culpa.

Comment: @Cfinley I know, right... Don't worry ash, some people think that they know best. That was an excellent answer, thank you. Joined this community just to upvote and comment. :)